# Updating HelloJni example

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, cygwin

This is probably a very easy question but since I am new to Cygwin and Ant, this annoyed me a lot.

Basically, I am trying to test hello-jni example that comes with NDK ( I use r8 currently).

I have set my paths and everything is working fine. However, when I simply cd to the sample directory and try to update the project, I get the following error.

Same error pops up when I actually append the path after -p

```
$ android.bat update project -p .
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.
```

ndk-build is working fine but whenever I try to install using Ant, I get the build.xml is missing error inevitably.

Thanks.

Comment: supply the target using the -t switch....

Comment: Well that worked, thanks for the help and sorry for my ignorance:).

Comment: Well actually, now I am encountering new errors. Since I'm a newbie in this, this again should be pretty easy for experienced people.

I am trying to launch san-angeles right now. I have updated the project and built it. I am trying to install it using "ant installr"  but the errors says release-apk does not exist. Any ideas people?

Comment: "ant debug install" should work

Answer (score 6):

run this command

```
android update project -p . -s --target android-14
```